# how to pass an array of string as a query parameter with same param name in Vue.js?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I want to pass the array of string along with key and value to the same param name as query parameter.

example query param list:

```
const params = {
  id: '002',
  sequence: [{ s1: 'a' }, { s2: 'b' }, { s3: 'c' }],
  limit: 3
};
```

URl should look like this.
`https://localhost:3000?id=002&sequence=s1=a&sequence=s2=b&sequence=s3=c`

how i can add logic here? any suggestion please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you would first need to iterate over your `params` object and then for the `array` inside the `object` you would have to conditionally iterate over it too and append each array element as a separate query parameter with the same key. And for non-array items in the object, append them as usual query parameters and then return the url after removing the leading `&`.

You can create a function for converting your params `object` to a URL string. Here's how the code would look like:

```js
const params = {
  id: '002',
  sequence: [{ s1: 'a' }, { s2: 'b' }, { s3: 'c' }],
  limit: 3
};

function convertParamsToURL(params) {
  let url = '';
  for (const key in params) {
    if (Array.isArray(params[key])) {
      params[key].forEach((item) => {
        for (const itemKey in item) {
          url += `&${key}=${itemKey}=${item[itemKey]}`;
        }
      });
    } else {
      url += `&${key}=${params[key]}`;
    }
  }
  return url.substring(1);
}

const baseUrl = 'https://localhost:3000';
const queryParam = convertParamsToURL(params);
const finalUrl = `${baseUrl}?${queryParam}`;
console.log(finalUrl)
```